# Can't access to VM using Vagrant user

Tags: linux, centos7, vagrant

I did change the vagrant user privileges this way:

```
$ grep vagrant /etc/passwd
  vagrant:x:0:0::/home/vagrant:/bin/sh
```

Then i logged out, now I can't login, What can I do to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: if you are using vagrant, recreate the vm with vagrant destroy -f && vagrant up and never do that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, another question, i got a Sonatype Nexus working in that vm, Do i going to loose the Nexus?

Comment: yes, if you destroy the vm.

Comment: There is no a way to recover that user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant uses ssh to log in using an ssh key. In changing the UID of the vagrant user (to 0) you've probably broken the rule which `sshd` imposes about ownership of the `authorized_keys` file.

From sshd(8):

> If this file, the ~/.ssh directory, or the user's home directory are
>   writable by other users, then the file could be modified or replaced
>   by unauthorized users.  In this case, sshd will not allow it to be
>   used unless the StrictModes option has been set to “no”.

If you must change the UID of vagrant then you could try changing the owner of the authorized_keys file to root:

```
chown root ~vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I've not actually tried this though!

Comment: Thank you, the answer is not modify de user the way i did.